# How to query a collection that can be null in JPQL?

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

Say I have an entity like this

```
class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "par")
    Set<Child> children

    String stuff;
}

class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="par_id", nullable=false)
    private Parent par;

    String value;
}
```

I want to have a query like this:

```
Select DISTINCT par from Parent par LEFT JOIN par.children chi 
WHERE
( par.stuff = :stuff or (:stuff is null))
AND ((chi is not empty) and chi.value = :value))
```

But this gives me back parents that have empty children.

I need to select all Parent that have a set of non empty children AND also children matching value = x

Comment: It would be easier to understand and help if you provided the mapping. Did you intentionally omitted it?

Comment: I edited the question, is that what you mean by mapping?

Comment: I mean object-relational mapping: JPA/hibernate annotations or hibernate xml configuration files.

Comment: Added the annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `inner join` to make sure children exists:

```sql
select distinct par from Parent par join par.children chi where chi.value = :value
```

You can use `exists` operator:

```sql
select distinct par from Parent par 
where exists 
 (select chi 
  from Child chi 
where chi.value = :value and chi.parent = par)
```